# How to prototype this circuit using an Arduino and breadboard?

Tags: electrical-engineering, circuits, electrical

I'm trying to build this circuit for a force transducer such that the data is logged by an Arduino Uno. I have the op-amp recommended in the schematic, but I haven't been able to get stable readings from the transducer. I've attached the schematics for the force transducer and op-amp, as well a picture of my attempt.

[image: Force Transducer]

[image: MCP6004]

[image: Schematic]

Comment: What reading are  you getting at Vout?

Comment: Also, what reading do you expect to get at Vout? I would isolate the problem to one component (Arduino, op-amp, transducer) by replacing each one or its input/output with something known such as voltmeter (on op-amp), ohmmeter (on transducer) or known voltage input (on Arduino, op-amp).